# Objective C - Memory Management Question?

Tags: objective-c, variables, memory-management, properties

I know that when setting a retained property to an allocated object it increments the retain count of the object so i need to release it (3rd line, first block of code)

But what if i don't have a property, and I am assigning an allocated object to an instant variable. Do i still need to release it????? (3rd line, second block of code)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
self.myObject = obj;
[obj release];
```

---

```
MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
myObject = obj;
[obj release];
```

**PLEASE read the full details before marking as duplicate**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that in both your examples the line standing on it's own is the property and the instance variable as defined in the class interface. And that the other code is executed from some method in that same class.

Lets look at what happens:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];  // Retain count = 1
self.myObject = obj;         // Retain count +1 (2), because property is defined
                             // as retain.
[obj release];               // Retain count -1
```

In this example everything works as it should. Lets look at the second one:

```
MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];  // Retain count = 1
myObject = obj;              // Retain count still 1. Assigns never changes
                             // retain counts.
[obj release];               // Retain count -1 (0), object is now deallocated.
                             // Any access to it though obj or myObject WILL
                             // cause a crash.
```

You can actually code Objective-C and treat it as almost 100% garbage collected, you just need to trust the auto release pools. Whenever you allocate an object you should also immediately hand it over to the auto release pool. That way you only need to worry about retaining what you want to survive past the end of the current method.

Your first example could be:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
self.myObject = obj;        // Implicitly retain through property
```

And your second would be:

```
MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
myObject = [obj retain];    // Explicitly retained to survive end of method
```

As you can see simply adding `autorelease` when allocating new objects, and consistently using properties will reduce memory management to just releasing instance variables in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Why bother adding something to the autorelease pool if you're just going to counter it with a retain?

Comment: Also, although traditionally in Cocoa the "retain count" term is used, Apple have moved away and instead use terms such as "ownership" (see the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)).

Comment: @dreamlax: actually, it's a fairly common pattern to immeditately autorelelease an allocated object (so you don't forget later).  The down vote is certainly harsh although you are correct about all that retain count stuff.

Comment: @JeremyP: Personally, I think it is unmethodical to do that. The rules say that you relinquish ownership by sending `release` or `autorelease`. Since you've relinquished ownership, it seems anti-MMR to send `retain` to it later (even though realistically it is doable since the docs say that autoreleased objects are generally still valid until the end of the scope).

Comment: @dreamlax: Because it is an easy and consistent way to get GC-like behavior than many developers are used to. That way new Objective-C developers can learn to crawl before they learn to walk. Demanding new devs to immediately grasp everything is elitists and counter productive.

Comment: I agree with @PeyloW on this one; I often create and immediately autorelease objects because I know I'm going to be flowing through code with multiple exit branches, and cleaning up all the relevant memory on each and every branch is tedious.  Simpler to just autorelease it and be done with it, since the object is guaranteed to exist until the end of the scope (at the very least).  However, I would still simplify @PeyloW's answer and just do: `myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];`

Comment: @PeyloW: The memory management rules are simple and easy to follow, even without understanding the underlying implementation of reference counts and autorelease pools. @Dave: I understand `autorelease` at the beginning of a method with multiple exits, but I'm talking specifically about PeyloW's init method which unnecessarily uses the autorelease pool for no significant advantage.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that when setting a retained property to an allocated object it increments the retain count of the object so i need to release it (3rd line, first block of code)

No, you don't know that.  For instance

```
foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"foo"];
[self setMyProperty: foo];
```

will not increment the retain count which will start off as INT_MAX and stay there.  However, **these are all implementation details and should not be thought about**.  You should really be thinking in terms of ownership and when you want to relinquish ownership.

In your first code block, the variable `obj` will go out of scope once the block it is in has been exited.  The reason you need to send `release` to it has nothing to do with the fact that you have assigned it to a property and everything to do with the fact that you are no longer interested in an object that you own (because the pointer to it is about to go out of scope).  By "you" incidentally, we mean the scope in which the pointer exists.

In the second case, you are assigning the object to an instance variables.  Instance variables live as long as the object they are an instance variable of.  Thus you need to own it until either the object is deallocated or the instance variable is changed to point to a different object.

Comment: +1 for addressing the issue wrt/ object ownership rather than implementation details or coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example both `obj` and `myObject` have been dealloc'd after you call `-release` since the retain count goes from 1 to zero.  In the first example, since your `@property` has "retain", the retain count goes from 1, to 2, then back to 1 when you release it, so it is not dealloc'd.

In short, you should *not* release objects you directly assign to ivars, except from within your `-dealloc` method, or before assigning something else to the same ivar.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you could remove the redundant variable `obj` and it would look like this:

```
MyObject *myObject; // declared as instance variable

//---//

myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[myObject release];
```

You can see straight away that `myObject` is deallocated immediately, because you have balanced your `alloc` with `release`.

When assigning directly to instance variables, you:

1. Generally do not need to use temporary/intermediate/auxiliary variables, especially for simple cases like the above.
2. Do not release it after assigning it.
3. Generally, ensure that the instance variable is not autoreleased (for example, do **not** use the convenience class methods, like `stringWithFormat:` and instead use the `alloc` + `initWithFormat:`, or, if you do use a convenience class method, make sure you explicitly `retain`).
4. As with properties, ensure that you `release` it in your class's `dealloc` method.

Comment: You would still be left with a dead object in `myObject` and a sure crash if the instance variable is ever touched.

Comment: @PeyloW: What are you talking about? I was showing what his second example boils down to, not recommending it.

Comment: You missed to read this part of the question: *" Do i still need to release it????? (3rd line, second block of code)"*.

Comment: @PeyloW: No, I said "2. Do not release after assigning it."

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @PeyloW's answer (which is 100% correct and should not have been down-voted)...

There are special circumstances which result in discouraging use of accessors in `-init` and `-dealloc`.  (Primarily key-value observing, but also overridden accessors that may have consequences/side effects that are not appropriate for a partially initialized or partially deallocated object)

Therefore, your `-init` method should probably be something like:

```
//@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject * myObject;

- (id) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  [myObject release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

And then everywhere else you would use `[self setMyObject:]` and `[self myObject]` (or `self.myObject`, if that's how you roll)